# Type of an f# expression

Tags: types, f#

I'm looking for a way to find out the type of an `f#` expression. Something similar to `Haskell's` `type` function.

Comment: IDE:s like VS & VS Code (+ Ionide) can help you with this. Otherwise what I do is that I assign the expression to an obviously invalid binding like so `let x : unit = the_expression`. The compiler will fail and tell you what it found that didn't match `unit`. If the compiler don't fail `the_expression` is unit. I don't think there's some like `_` in haskell to ask the compiler "What do you expect here?".

Comment: Thanks. Turn it into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDE:s like VS & VS Code (+ Ionide) can help you with this. Otherwise what I do is that I assign the expression to an obviously invalid binding like:

```
let x : unit = <the_expression>
```

The compiler will fail and tell you what it found that didn't match unit. If the compiler doesn't fail the `_` expression is unit. I don't think there's some like `_` in haskell to ask the compiler "What do you expect here?".